# Why does calling this function twice cause an error?

Tags: python

I am having a problem with calling a function twice. If I comment my last 3 lines and keep `show()`, I don't get any errors and things come as they are suppose to. However, if I don't comment them out calling the last function again gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "second_1.py", line 29, in <module>
    domega=c_d(len(t),t,z)
  File "second_1.py", line 25, in c_d
    dy[1:-1]=(y[2:]-y[0:-2])/(x[2:]-x[0:-2])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
```

Here is the function:

```
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
import time

t_initial=time.time()
clf()
t,hp,hn= np.loadtxt("Richardson.dat", usecols=(0,1,2),comments='#', unpack=True)     # to select just a few columns
print(time.time()-t_initial)  

def phi(y,x):
    return(np.arctan(y/x))

phase=[0.0]*len(t)
phase=phi(hp[0:],hn[0:])
#plot(t,phase)
#show()    

def c_d(order,x,y):
    dy=[0.0]*order
    dy[0]=(y[1]-y[0])/(x[1]-x[0])
    dy[-1]=(y[-1]-y[-2])/(x[-1]-x[-2])
    dy[1:-1]=(y[2:]-y[0:-2])/(x[2:]-x[0:-2])
    return(dy);
    z=c_d(len(t),t,phase);
    plot(t,z)
    print(len(z)-len(t))
    domega=c_d(len(t),t,z)
    plot(t,domega)
    show()
```

Comment: Read the error message, there is no `-` operator for lists. Your syntax `y[2:]` for example will make a slice, **which is a list** you cannot subtract lists

Comment: Not entirely clear what you are trying to do. Try making those lists `numpy` arrays, e.g. `x = np.array(x)`. For those, `-` can be used.

Comment: I think @tobias_k 's comment hits the nail on the head. Seen the use of the pylab and numpy imports, the OP is used to working with arrays, and has Python lists and numpy arrays confused. Additional note: `from pylab import *` will include everything from numpy; as far as I know, `from pylab import *` is short for `from pyplot import *; from numpy import *`. It is also recommended to *not* use those kind of imports. `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt` is often better and clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the other answers, you can not subtract regular Python lists. So why does it work the first time, and fails the second? Let's take a look at the code.

```
t, hp, hn = np.loadtxt(...)
...
def c_d(order, x, y):
    dy       = [0.0] * order
    dy[ 0]   = (y[1] -y[0])    / (x[ 1]-x[0])
    dy[-1]   = (y[-1]-y[-2])   / (x[-1]-x[-2])
    dy[1:-1] = (y[2:]-y[0:-2]) / (x[2:]-x[0:-2])
    return dy

z = c_d(len(t), t, phase)
...
domega = c_d(len(t), t, z)
...
```

When you first call `c_d`, the parameters `x` and `y` seem to be `numpy` arrays (at least `t` and `phase` are results of `numpy` function calls), and for those, `-` is a legal operation. But inside `c_d`, you create and finally return a *regular* Python list, `dy`, so when you then call `c_d` *again* with the result of the first call as `y`, this part `y[2:]-y[0:-2]` will fail, as `y` now is a regular list.

Make sure your `dy` is a `numpy` array, too, i.e. `dy = np.array([0.0]  *order)` or just `dy = np.zeros(order)`, then it should work.

Comment: great help by you @tobias . I accidentally did the same (without having in mind wt difference it will make) .But thanks for explaining it dude. It worked perfectly. Thnks for ur time and effort :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is very clearly explained in the error message:
The '-' operand is not applicable for the type list.

```
(y[2:]-y[0:-2])/(x[2:]-x[0:-2])
```

y[2:] slices a list and returns a list. y[0:-2] slices also a list and returns a list. So there you have 2 lists.

```
y[2:] (a list)   -(your operator)   y[0:-2] (a list)
```

And list - list is not defined (there is no syntax for: 'listObject' - 'listObject').

BUT: the + operator is defined for lists (example):

```
l = ["ja"]
m = ["nein"]

n = l + m

print n
# output: ['ja', 'nein']
```

Take a look here for these different kind of possible operators:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html

Comment: More precisely, you can use negative indexing in lists, but your problem is where you're trying to subtract one list from another.

Comment: @RyanO'Donnell: Yes, I was not talking about slicing, I'll edit my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Cyber and ProgrammingIsAwsome the error is on line

```
(y[2:]-y[0:-2])/(x[2:]-x[0:-2])
```

where you actually try to substract lists.

You could write explicitely :

```
for i in range(1, order - 1):
    dy[i]=(y[i+1]-y[i-1])/(x[i+1]-x[1-1])
```

Comment: I dnt prefer for loop. Bt   tobias_k explanation worked for me. I have conceptual problem when python create list and whn it generate array .

Comment: @AwanishAwanish Python but itself only uses lists. `numpy` allows you to use arrays.